# Xcode 6 beta 2 simulator keeps displaying a black screen nondeterministically

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uikit, swift

I'm having a very frustrating problem with Xcode 6 beta 2's iPhone simulator. I can get my first couple of views to show fine, but for some reason, one transition keeps failing nondeterministically.

Sometimes it will work great. But the vast majority of the time, the simulator will just go to a blank black page. No errors are logged, and the app does not crash.

Specifically, I am transitioning programmatically to another view when the user clicks on an entry in a TableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        let vc : EventListViewController! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventListViewController") as EventListViewController
        vc.dataToPassAlong = tableData[indexPath.row]
        self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
    }
```

All the view controllers have been labeled with their appropriate storyboard identifiers, and dataToPassAlong is a property in EventListViewController.

Transitions between views before this particular transition are fine. Even this specific transition works flawlessly sometimes. But it's about a 80-20 chance that clicking on a TableView row causes the simulator to black screen.

So far, the only thing that has helped a tiny bit is restarting Xcode every time this happens, but even that has stopped working (so it might not have been the solution in the first place).

Did I mess up something simple? Am I missing some nuance of cocoa/UIKit that's causing this nondeterministic behavior? Or is the Xcode beta just this buggy?

Answer (score 0):

did you try cleaning out your derived data folder. i've also had the same issue, but once i cleaned out the derived data folder. everything seems to work fine.

the derived data folder is located under Preferences>location click on the little arrow that shows the destination. where you can delete the folder and run the file again.

Comment: Unfortunately I stopped working on this project a year ago - I encountered several other weird behaviors that I just ended up chalking up to a buggy XCode beta (it was very new at the time).